# Sell our home or rent it?

Tags: united-states, stocks, home-ownership, utah

**Scenario & Question**

We are trying to decide if we should sell our home or rent it out because it's in a good location. Would it be better to rent out our home or sell it and invest the gains (50k).

**My Thoughts**

Theoretically we should get 3-5% increase per year owning the property while the more volatile S&P averages 12% a year. This screams to me that a well diversified portfolio should well outpace owning the home.

Am I missing something ?

**EDIT**

Additional Details:

This is regarding a property that is currently mortgaged (30yr 3% starting 6/2019). That said I do have another property that I may sell via 1031 depending on my findings of rent vs own (30yr 4.6% starting 7/2007).

Comment: @KateGregory In our case the mortgage + repairs would wash out most of the rental income, that said there is still the 3-5% appreciation on the property. I've also had a separate rental for 15yrs which has done great but a group of mutual funds I joined in 2016 has brought in more money in just 6 years (I do realize the market as been pretty hot after the 2008 recovery).

Comment: That's where I've been getting stuck, hence my journey to SE money. The rate is 3% which is great all things considered. I really want to find a good excuse to keep this property but the numbers just don't support it.

Comment: The comparison of a 3-5% gain in property value vs. a 12% gain in S&P is basically a comparison between simply selling the house now or selling the house later, but that's not the choice being considered - the choice is to sell now or to sell later *and collect rent* in the meantime. There is some amount of rent that makes the latter more profitable, the question is how likely you'd be to earn that in practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over the last 20 years average home price in Utah has increased ~6%/year, ~9.7%/year over the last 10 years. S&P500 over those two periods has averaged 2-3%/year more than home prices in Utah. It's anyone's guess as to what the markets will bring, real-estate performance can vary significantly within a state. Right now you have leverage amplifying your gain/loss potential compared to just investing the sale proceeds.

> mortgage + repairs would wash out most of the rental income

That doesn't mean the only benefit you get is from increase in property value, you're getting equity every month by someone else paying the mortgage. Similarly, if the value continues to increase so too will your rent, which should increase cash flow. You'll want to properly calculate your ROI as part of your decision. I suggest setting up a spreadsheet and forecasting a few scenarios for each (historical average, optimistic, pessimistic) and compare that way.

Ultimately it depends on your preferences and outlook. If you like being a landlord well enough and you think home prices won't grossly underperform the stock market then being leveraged at a low interest rate could work out very well. If you are wanting to sell anyway and think real estate will underperform then you should sell.

Personally, I like being a landlord and view it as a form of diversification since my 401k/IRA/brokerage accounts are pretty much all stocks/options, but it's not for everyone and certainly not guaranteed to be profitable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as I can figure, the "answer" I am looking for (which you highlight) is relative to the the individual because at some point the fiscal value becomes somewhat irrelevant (500k-1m+) ie. "whatever you *want* to do is what you *should* do". I enjoyed working with rentals for years because I enjoyed the manual fixer-upper and DIY labor but now with young kids and a steady career in software my time is sapped so I'm looking for the more passive revenue stream which seems to lead toward diversified investing.

Comment: @Jacksonkr I'm not a fan of paying for property management, but many people do that if their rentals are far away or they just don't want to spend as much time on it. I added a bit to the section about calculating ROI, you really should set up a spreadsheet and compare to know exactly what you might be giving up/gaining.

Comment: I've used a property management group @ 7%/mo while one of my managed account's groups takes 1% yearly; I'm certain the rate difference is due to investment accounts ability of being pooled together similar to a cleaning service. I did a spreadsheet a while back and I'm about at the tipping point (depending on market volatility of course) hence me publicizing my plans in hopes of constructive criticism from others as well as a "final" review for myself.

Comment: @Jacksonkr It will be interesting to see what happens with interest rates and housing prices. After a bunch of re-financing in past couple years I have no interest in giving up low rates even if housing prices decline significantly in the short-term. Who knows though.

Comment: Home price increases have been fantastic the last 20 years primarily due to an unsustainably low interest rates. Demand has plummeted as interest rates rise. Prices have yet to fall, as inventory is as tight as demand is low. It may be that low inventory is a permanent situation and that price decreases are a thing of the past, but I'm skeptical. If current inflation rates last into next year mortgage rates need to return to 1970s levels of 10%+, which will be a very strong weight on prices.

Comment: Update: We had a buyer back out on the last day they could before losing their earnest money and after that we have decided to stay. Furthermore, domestic rentals aren't for everyone but there are REIT's which is a good alternative eg. sell your home under section 121 tax exclusion and invest in a good REIT.

Answer (score 2):

You mention you have 50k of equity and could earn 10-12% on it. That's 5-6k a year.

You seem to feel that the rental income will just cover the mortgage payment, property taxes, and the expenses of maintaining and renting the unit. Ok. What fraction of that mortgage payment is principal? If it's 400 a month, that's 5k a year your equity is increasing while the renters pay your mortgage for you.

Then there's the increase in the property value. If it's a 100k property, 5% a year is 5k - which matches what your equity could earn elsewhere. If you're highly leveraged and it's a 500k property, 5% of that is 25k a year. That's a lot more than 5. In fact, it's a lot more than 0, which may be all it needs to go up by if the principal part of your mortgage payment can match what the equity would earn elsewhere.

Comment: These are all good points so first off, thanks for your answer. I suppose my biggest worry is that the Utah market has been exceedingly hot and with fed rate increases we seem to be heading back toward a buyer's market. 2) 5% of 500k is 25k while 12% of 500k is 60k so even if I keep this place now there becomes a point at which having 500k invested significantly outpaces 500k in property. I'd need multiple properties to counter that and why not own shares in REIT's at that point? (sincere question)

Comment: but if you sell the house you don't get 500k to invest. You get your equity and you don't have to pay the mortgage. If the house was paid off, the math would be different, yes.

Comment: Valid point - I think this is where it kind of gets into a "tomato tomatoe" situation where it's more about the enjoyment of one strategy vs another. Full disclosure I have a diversified (mostly tech) investment account which doubled in about 5 years but I must realize that the market has been more hot than cold since 2008 and it's unlikely to stay that way. I also plan to invest in REIT's in lieu of owning tangible property.